# ROS Answers SE migration: orocos-bfl

Tags: ros, navigation, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I was trying to `catkin_make` "robot_pose_ekf" package I cloned from github and it's CMakeLists.txt is: [link text](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/robot_pose_ekf/CMakeLists.txt). The output error was:

```
checking for module 'orocos-bfl'

--   package 'orocos-bfl' not found

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:340 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:502 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

<== Failed to process package 'robot_pose_ekf':
```

Then I cloned "orocos-bfl" package from github and when I `catkin_make` it, the output was:

```
Packages not found in the workspace: orocos-bfl
```

Then I followed [bfl-ROS.wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl) the following lines to CMakeLists.txt of "robot_pose_ekf" package:

```
   1 find_package(PkgConfig)
   2 
   3 pkg_check_modules(BFL REQUIRED bfl)
   4 
   5 message("BFL include dirs:" ${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   6 message("BFL library dirs:" ${BFL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
   7 
   8 include_directories(${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   9 link_directories(${BFL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  10 
  11 [..]
  12 
  13 # for every target using BFL:
  14 target_link_libraries(your_executable ${BFL_LIBRARIES})
```

In the original CMakeLists.txt there is a line:

```
pkg_check_modules(BFL REQUIRED orocos-bfl)
```

and I just substituted is `orocos-bfl` with `bfl` as suggested and insert rest of above lines.
The result was, this did not work, output was:

```
package 'bfl' not found
```

which is installed already and can be found by rospack:

```
/Users/hxin1/ros_catkin_ws/src/bfl-release-release-indigo-bfl-0.7.0-6
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204942/orocos-bfl/) by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

orocos-bfl is not a catkin package but a plain cmake package. The `package 'bfl' not found` comes from cmake / pkgconfig, not catkin.

You cannot build `orocos-bfl` with `caktin_make`. Either use `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin build` in the same workspace as `robot_pose_ekf`, or first build `orocos-bfl` in an underlying workspace (with `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin_build`) and then build `robot_pose_ekf` ontop of that in a separate workspace using `catkin_make`.

**Edit:**

The following works for me:

```
rosinstall_generator robot_pose_ekf --tar --wet-only --rosdistro indigo --deps > robot_pose_ekf.rosinstall
wstool init -j8 src robot_pose_ekf.rosinstall 
src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated
```

as does with `catkin build` instead of `src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated`.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-03-13**:
This works for me too. Thanks a lot and I think I learnt a lot from you!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-03-13**:
Good to know. Happy hacking :-).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:  If using ROS-kinetic, you can just apt-get install ros-kinetic-bfl.  This must be present to compile the navigation stack (move_base).

---

Originally posted by [howardcochran](https://answers.ros.org/users/28150/howardcochran/) with karma: 76 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1